# How to setup IKEv2 VPN client on TP Link ER605 V2

Tags: networking, router, vpn, nordvpn

I use NordVPN and wanted to set it up network-wide using my TP Link ER605 V2 router. It claims IKEv2 support, but seems to require a pre-shared key (Which Nord doesn't offer) instead of an option for just a username/password for authentication.

Is there any other way to set it up using IKEv2, even if using custom firmware? If not, any suggestions for a simple router or device that could be used as an IKEv2 client with just a username/password to authenticate? Doesn't need wifi etc, just a bare bones VPN device to sit in the middle between my modem and main switch.

I know the ER605 supports OpenVPN, but I've tried that and it absolutely tanks our speed. So I'd prefer to stick to IKEv2 even if it means buying a new device.

Comment: Nord provides a [client certificate for IKEv2/IPsec connections](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Windows/1047410092/How-to-connect-to-NordVPN-with-IKEv2-IPSec-on-Windows-10.htm). If the router supports OpenWRT or similar (see [here](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Router/1047409322/Setting-up-a-router-with-NordVPN.htm)) you might be able to utilize the cert. The entire router support is pretty new for Nord so PSK-authentication might be in the pipeline. Talk to their support, I've found them pretty responsive.

Comment: Doesn’t seem that would be possible with the ER605. I did check in with support but seems they won’t comment much on anything that isn’t already on the website. Any suggestions for a basic router that would support IKEv2 with username/password auth at the moment? @Peregrino69

Comment: Ah. Well, the 1st line guys have a limited set of tools... I've usually gotten through to 2nd line when needed. But I did keep bugging them about the router connectivity for about 3 years so... Sorry I don't know which ones might work beyond their recommendations. They've now partnered with Wireguard, the [Wireguard NordLynx WiFi 6 Router - Privacy Hero](https://www.flashrouters.com/privacy-hero-vpn-router-by-flashrouters) works with NordLynx protocol.